# Using modules in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny dashboard and I wanted to incorporate shiny modules. In each tab the UI of the app is very similar with a selectInput, dateRangeInput, and an action button of the same dataset. Therefore, I thought that it would significantly shorten the code if I would apply modules. My first attempt was with an actionbutton module and I would like to get your feedback if I am approaching it the right way or if you have any suggestions for improvements.

The idea of the mini app below is that the data and the plot get updated only when you click the corresponding button (button 1 for plot 1 and button 2 for plot 2).

This is a small example, but consider a shiny dashboard with 20 different tabs and I thought that it would make the code easier to read having only a button_ui instead of writing the button ui every time for each tab. Similarly I would like to have something similar for select_ui and daterange_ui.

```
ec <- data.frame(
       country = c("US", "UK", "Germany", "Spain", "India"), 
       A  = c("1", "2", "2", "3", "3"), 
       B = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
   )

## MODULE 
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

button_ui <- function(id) {
  actionButton(NS(id, "btn"), label = "Apply")
}

button_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    reactive(input$btn)
  })
}

## BUILDING THE APP 

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(
    "choice",
    "Select Country:",
    multiple = TRUE,
    choices = unique(ec$country),
    selected = "US"),
  
  button_ui("btn1"),
  button_ui("btn2"),
  plotOutput("plot1"),
  br(),
  plotOutput("plot2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  button <- button_server("btn1")
  button_a <- button_server("btn2")
  
  dt <- reactive({button()
    isolate(
    ec %>% filter(country %in% input$choice)
    )
  })
  
  dt1 <- reactive({button_a()
    isolate(
      ec %>% filter(country %in% input$choice)
    )
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dt(), aes(x = country, y = A)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
      theme_test()
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dt1(), aes(x = country, y = B)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
      theme_test()
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general use of modules is correct, but I think your actionbutton module is too fine graned. You basically wrap a module around only one UI element, so you generate more overhead than usefulness. However, I think in your case it makes sense to combine the `selectInput` and the plot output together in one module. You can see this in the example below. I also changed the following points:

- instead of `reactive` and `isolate`, I use `eventReactive`
- I use the new module interface from shiny 1.5.0

```
ec <- data.frame(
  country = c("US", "UK", "Germany", "Spain", "India"), 
  A  = c("1", "2", "2", "3", "3"), 
  B = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
)

## MODULE 
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


tab_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(
    title = paste0("Plot ", id),
    selectInput(
      ns("choice"),
      "Select Country:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = unique(ec$country),
      selected = "US"),
    actionButton(ns("btn"), label = "Apply"),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
    
  )
  
}

tab_module <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      dt <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
          ec %>% filter(country %in% input$choice)
      })
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(dt(), aes(x = country, y = A)) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
          theme_test()
      })
    }
  )
}

## BUILDING THE APP 

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tab_module_ui("plot-1"),
    tab_module_ui("plot-2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  tab_module("plot-1")
  tab_module("plot-2")
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That seems to makes a lot more sense. Thanks for your suggestion @starja. May I ask why you use eventReactive instead of reactive and isolate in the case at hand?

Comment: At least in my case, it already showed plots before the first time clicking the button. Also, `eventReactive` is exactly the function that provides the functionality you want: it generates a reactive output, that only changes when the value of the first expression (the action button) changes. So you need to type less and by looking at the code, you can directly infer the behaviour of this reactive (you don't have to look for `isolate` statements which could be more complicated in more complex code).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense